# Swift Scope Button Text Color

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am having a problem with my UI of my app. I don't know how to edit the color of the buttons on the scope bar to make them clearer.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a UISegmentedControl ? programatically or in InterfaceBuilder ? check [setTitleTextAttributes:forState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:)

Comment: I am using the InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: Try changing the 'tint' in the Attributes inspector

Comment: That fixed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you..

```
self.segControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];



[self.segControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html